# How to add submodule from reference an existing project rather than clone a new repo

Tags: git

There are 2 projects,all of them have github repo:A,B.The project A reference project B .
The

I used to compile using my local pc , now I change to use AppCenter with submodule function.

I use SourceTree to manage git( I don't like commandline, and I only use fundmental functions , sourceTree is already enough)

Git submodule will clone a repo from project B 's github repo , and  then I change project A's reference to new cloned repoB . It can work in AppCenter.

But I didn't find any other ways to reference existing projectB , if I use `git submodule add https://github.com/me/B.git ..\ProjectB` to try to match the existing repo ,It will show the error "fatal: ../ProjectB: '../ProjectB' is outside repository at 'D:/Projects/ProjectA'"

I tried to manully edit the .gitsubmodule file ,It can't work.

How to reference an existing repo?